# Reading huge integers with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got some json with huge integers, in the order of a few hundred digits. I'd like to parse those as BouncyCastle's `BigInteger` (https://github.com/onovotny/BouncyCastle-PCL/blob/pcl/crypto/src/math/BigInteger.cs).

```
{
    "bigNumber":12093812947635091350945141034598534526723049126743245...
}
```

So I've implemented a converter, using a contract resolver in the default settings.

```
internal class BigIntegerConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken jToken = JToken.Load(reader);
        return new BigInteger(jToken.ToString());
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(BigInteger));
    }
}

public class BigIntegerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private static readonly JsonConverter bigIntegerConverter = new BigIntegerConverter();
    private static Type type = typeof(BigInteger);

    protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == type)
        {
            return bigIntegerConverter;
        }
        return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
    }
}

JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new BigIntegerContractResolver()
        };
```

The writer works as it should, writing a (large) integer value instead of the class BigInteger with all its properties etc. However, the reading fails. Neither ReadJson nor CanConvert appear to be invoked.

I get the following exception:

JsonReaderException: JSON integer 340597435091750914358634185762341897561435984635897436598435643875643189576413589743659817456... is too large or small for an Int64.

How do I get Json.NET to parse this number as a string instead of an integer?

Ideally I don't want to have to parse the json string myself first, to add quotes.

Comment: Why do you not using `System.Numerics.BigInteger`?

Comment: A lot of the BouncyCastle API uses their own BigInteger class. I think they chose to implement the java BigInteger in order to make it easier to port from the java codebase. Since I'm using the BC API to work with these numbers, it makes sense to deserialize them as such.

Comment: Ok. Is the method `CanConvert` ever called?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call the deserialization

Comment: @CSharper No, it doesn't appear to be called.

Comment: @dlght Done, see my edit.

Comment: @CSharper [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Numerics.BigInteger) was not introduced until 2010 (.NET 4.0), so a good guess is BouncyCastle's type was originally written earlier than that.

Comment: @qxwevr set in your json settings `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects`. I guess he does not know which type it is and tries to resolve the number as `int64` first, before he uses your custom resolver.

Comment: @CSharper I don't have control over how I receive the serialized Json. But I guess this doesn't seem possible, and I'll have to manually modify the json before deserializing it.

Answer (score 5):

If your large number isn't quoted, Json.Net will deserialize it as a `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.  This happens inside the `JsonTextReader`, well before the converter gets a chance to handle it.  So if you want your result type to be `Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger`, you'll need to convert from `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.  (Seems a little backwards, I know.  The other alternative is to create your own `JsonTextReader`, but that is probably going to be more trouble than it is worth -- most of the useful bits of the existing reader are in private or internal methods, so subclassing it is not practical.)

I was able to get this converter to work:

```
class BigIntegerConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        System.Numerics.BigInteger big = (System.Numerics.BigInteger)reader.Value;
        return new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(big.ToString());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is the test program I used.  Note that I did not use a resolver. `JsonSerializerSettings` has a `Converters` collection, so I just added the `BigIntegerConverter` to that.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""bigNumber"": 12093812947635091350945141034598534526723049126743245
        }";

        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new BigIntegerConverter() }
        };

        Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.BigNumber.ToString());
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger BigNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
12093812947635091350945141034598534526723049126743245
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating object that handles the output of the json like this:

```
public class YourModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter<BigInteger>))]
    public BigInteger YourProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

And now it can become more generic for every type you need:

```
public class CustomConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        your code ..
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //explicitly specify the concrete type we want to create
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        your code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but ReadJson isn't being called at all.

Comment: i like to add it to my options when I serialize the string