# Reading BigInteger in C# with JSON.NET JsonTextReader

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-8.1, json.net

I'm trying to get a **BigInteger** (System.Numerics) from a json using Json.NET on Windows Phone 8.1, but I get an *Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException*.

To reproduce the error, I've reduced my code to this snippet:

```
    string json = @"{
       'BFN': 123456789012345678901234
    }";

    JsonTextReader jTR = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));

    while (jTR.Read())
    {
        if (jTR.Value != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Token: {0}, Value: {1}", jTR.TokenType, jTR.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Token: {0}", jTR.TokenType);
        }
    }
```

Running this code gets the following error at *jTR.Read()*:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: JSON integer 123456789012345678901234 is too
>   large or small for an Int64.

As far as I can tell from the source code, this exception is thrown at line 2010 in *JsonTextReader*, but I can't get my head around the reason why it's trying to use Int64 and not BigInteger.

Any help or information is greatly appreciated.

Json.NET version: 8.0.3

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076200/reading-huge-integers-with-json-net

Comment: @rbm I found this thread before, but in my case System.Numerics.BigInteger would be the preferred type for the result. As I understand it, JsonTextReader uses the same type, so I don't understand why it can't parse the value of BFN as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L1999) for `JsonTextReader` has this:

```
#if !(NET20 || NET35 || PORTABLE40 || PORTABLE)

    string number = _stringReference.ToString();

    if (number.Length > MaximumJavascriptIntegerCharacterLength)
    {
        throw JsonReaderException.Create(this, "JSON integer {0} is too large to parse.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
    }

    numberValue = BigIntegerParse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    numberType = JsonToken.Integer;

#else

    throw JsonReaderException.Create(this, "JSON integer {0} is too large or small for an Int64.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));

#endif
```

Notice there are conditional compilation directives in there.  In short, if you are using the portable versions of the Json.Net library (which I'm assuming you are if it's Windows Phone), then `BigInteger` is not supported.

If you have control over the format of the JSON, try quoting the large number such that it is a string instead of a bare integer.  That will allow Json.Net to read it.  If you really need to interpret it as a large number, you can use a third-party library to parse it from the string and work with it that way.

Comment: I had a hunch, that this was the problem, but I couldn't find out if the portable version was used (looking back it's kind of a 'duh' situation). Unfortunately the JSON is pretty much fixed, I can't modify the format.