# How to Deserialize a JSON Object With a Very Large Interger Value in .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to deserialize a JSON response from `https://api.huobi.pro/market/history/trade?symbol=btcusdt` endpoint. However, the response includes a very big number which exceeds the capacity of ulong in C#, and I am getting exceptions while deserializing with  `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize` (also with  `Newtonsoft.Json`). The problematic filed is the innermost "id" field of the response. I tried using `BigNumber` on my data model but didn't help. How can I deserialize this object?

The response structure:

```
{"ch":"market.btcusdt.trade.detail","status":"ok","ts":1675717627951,"data":[{"id":161853359895,"ts":1675717624799,"data":[{"id":161853359895718430859199824,"ts":1675717624799,"trade-id":102753924495,"amount":0.01998,"price":22983.98,"direction":"buy"}]}]}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't deserialize it to a string?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33084514/10809344t) can push you in the right direction? It talks about dealing with a different big int class, but I think you might be able to reuse the concept from it

Comment: @David I tried that but it says "Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string." when I change the type of field id to string.

Comment: @smgtkn System.Text.Json will choke on serializing the value to a string, but Json.Net handles it just fine. Json.Net also handles serializing to BigInteger. Perhaps you need to clarify your question to target just _ONE_ serializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use a BigInteger property.This code was tested and working properly

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Numerics;

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);


public class Datum
{
    public BigInteger id { get; set; }
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trade-id")]
    public long tradeid { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string ch { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This fails for some reason. Exception message: "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Numerics.BigInteger. Path: $.data[0].data[0].id" @Serge

Comment: @smgtkn I am using Newtonsoft.Json and highly recomend it to you instead of Text.Json

Comment: desterilise it as string, then convert :)